# How to map elements of array to an input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state variable which is an array. Each element is a string. I am trying to map each element to a checkbox input type, but it fails.

When I try to map them to a p tag to segregate each element into different paragraphs, it works. But when I use input type it shows blank.

```
return (
  <div className="pdf" id="check">
    {this.state.content.map((txt) =>
      <p><input type='checkbox' value={txt} /></p>
    )}
  </div>
```

Here this.state.content is an array of string elements, and with only p tag it works fine but after including input tag it renders the checkboxes but content is blank.

I need a checkbox at the start of each element when I print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as the "value" of a checkbox. It is either checked or unchecked. To show some text next to the checkbox, add some text outside of it:

```
 <p>{text} <input type="checkbox" /></p>
```